# Batch Move files to sub-directory from list.txt

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, cmd.exe

Good day.
I have researched this quetion on this site and can't find the answer I am looking for. Sorry to post something that sounds similar to other posts.

I have a text document "ListedFiles.txt". It has all the directories of all the files of where they belong. What I am trying to do is take the Text document and move all the files in the Parent directory into the SubDirectories listed in the text.

I keep getting "Duplicate error" every time I process this code. Anyone think they can solve my problem? It should be a relatively simple fix, I think.

```
@echo off
set dir=C:\Users\user\texture\
set mask=ListedFiles.txt

cd "%dir%"
for /r %%# in (%mask%) do echo move "%%~#"&echo mklink /h "%%~#" "%%~nx#"
pause
```

Without link

```
set dir=C:\Users\user\texture\
set mask=*.bmp

cd "%dir%"
for /r %%# in (%mask%) do move "%%~#"
pause
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what would be in ListedFiles.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the text file is some...

```bash
like this         ..or  like this
.\000_000\000.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\000_000\000.bmp
.\001_001\001.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\001_001\001.bmp
.\002_002\002.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\002_002\002.bmp
.\003_003\003.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\003_003\003.bmp
.\004_004\004.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\004_004\004.bmp
.\005_005\005.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\005_005\005.bmp
.\006_006\006.bmp       C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture\006_006\006.bmp
```

Try this:

- Command line:

```bash
cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" && for /f useback^delims^= %i in (`type list_dir_files.txt`)do @move /y .\"%~nxi" "%~i" 2>nul || @echo; Check: .\"%~nxi" "%~i"
```

---

- Bath file:

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" 2>nul || exit /b 
           
for /f useback^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` type .\"list_dir_files.txt"
    `);= do 2>nul move /y .\"%%~nxi" "%%~i" || echo; Check: .\"%%~nxi" "%%~i"
```

---

---

If the content of the text file is some...

```bash
 like this          ..or  like this         ..or  like this
 .\000_000\000.bmp        \000_000\000.bmp        000_000\000.bmp
 .\001_001\001.bmp        \001_001\001.bmp        001_001\001.bmp
 .\002_002\002.bmp        \002_002\002.bmp        002_002\002.bmp
 .\003_003\003.bmp        \003_003\003.bmp        003_003\003.bmp
 .\004_004\004.bmp        \004_004\004.bmp        004_004\004.bmp
 .\005_005\005.bmp        \005_005\005.bmp        005_005\005.bmp
 .\006_006\006.bmp        \006_006\006.bmp        006_006\006.bmp
```

Try this:

- Command line:

```bash
cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" && for /f useback^delims^= %i in (`type list_dir_files.txt`)do @move /y .\"%~nxi" "%cd%\%~i" 2>nul || @echo; Check: .\"%~nxi" "%cd%\%~i"
```

---

- Bath file:

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" 2>nul || exit /b 
           
for /f useback^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` type .\"list_dir_files.txt"
    `);= do 2>nul move /y .\"%%~nxi" "%%~i" || echo; Check: .\"%%~nxi" "%%~i"
```

---

---

If the content of the text file is some...

```bash
like this          ..or  like this
./000_000/000.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/000_000/000.bmp
./001_001/001.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/001_001/001.bmp
./002_002/002.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/002_002/002.bmp
./003_003/003.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/003_003/003.bmp
./004_004/004.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/004_004/004.bmp
./005_005/005.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/005_005/005.bmp
./006_006/006.bmp        C:/Users/rivers/Desktop/data hd/texture/006_006/006.bmp
```

Try this:

- Command line:

```bash
cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" && for /f usebackq^delims^= %i in (`type list_dir_files.txt`)do @set "_str=" & =;@(set "_str=%~i" & call move /y .\"%~nxi" "%_str:/=\%" || call echo; Check: .\"%~nxi" "%_str:/=\%" );= 2>nul
```

- Bath file:

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" 2>nul || exit /b 

for /f useback^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` type .\"list_dir_files.txt" `);= do set "_str=" & 2>nul =;(
    set "_str=%%~i" & call move /y .\"%%~nxi" "%%_str:/=\%%" || call echo; Check: .\"%%~nxi" "%%_str:/=\%%" 
   );=
```

---

If the content of the text file is some...

```bash
 like this          ..or  like this         ..or  like this
 ./000_000/000.bmp        /000_000/000.bmp        000_000/000.bmp
 ./001_001/001.bmp        /001_001/001.bmp        001_001/001.bmp
 ./002_002/002.bmp        /002_002/002.bmp        002_002/002.bmp
 ./003_003/003.bmp        /003_003/003.bmp        003_003/003.bmp
 ./004_004/004.bmp        /004_004/004.bmp        004_004/004.bmp
 ./005_005/005.bmp        /005_005/005.bmp        005_005/005.bmp
 ./006_006/006.bmp        /006_006/006.bmp        006_006/006.bmp
```

Try this:

- Command line:

```
cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture"  && for /f useback^tokens^=*^delims^= %i in =;(` type .\"list_dir_files.txt" `);= do @set "_str=" &  =;@( set "_str=%CD%\%~i" & call move /y .\"%~nxi" "%_str:/=\%" || call echo; Check: .\"%~nxi" "%_str:/=\%" );= 2>nul
```

- Bath file:

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data hd\texture" 2>nul || exit /b 

for /f useback^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` type .\"list_dir_files.txt" `);= do set "_str=" & 2>nul =;(
     set "_str=%CD%\%%~i" & call move /y .\"%%~nxi" "%%_str:/=\%%" || call echo; Check: .\"%%~nxi" "%%_str:/=\%%" 
    );=
```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Thank you so much. This was it. This was it on so many levels and I had to research so much just to understand it. Thanks for the lesson and resources. I hope others learn from this kind of batch manipulation.

Comment: The layout of your file was left incognito, so I had to diversify the possible distributions of the **"`paths\to\the\file.eXt`"** d;)

Comment: If I were to now take all the files from a single directory and put them into folders, even if it means creating them. Is that possible? Here's an example of what my listing looks like.

`\data\sprite\·Îºê\gerhard_von_devi_bag\³²\cardinal_³².bmp
\data\sprite\·Îºê\giantcatbag\¿©\Å¸Á¶·¹ÀÎÁ®_¿©.bmp
\data\sprite\·Îºê\bag\¿©\È­ÀÌÆ®½º¹Ì½º_¿©.bmp`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply. I ended up getting an answer!
Your hard work has prevailed.

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\complete\texture" 2>nul || exit /b 
           
for /f usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` type .\"ListedFiles.txt"
    `);= do 2>nul move /y .\"%%~nxi" "%%~i" || echo; Check: .\"%%~nxi" "%%~i"
```

---

**Obs.:** Whether your folder list contains double quotes around the listed items or not will not affect the result.

> If the folder listed in the file does not exist and needs to be created to move the file to the folder, use `robocopy` instead of the `move` command:

---

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\complete\texture" 2>nul || exit /b 
           
for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` 
     type .\"ListedFiles.txt" ^| findstr . `);= do 2>nul =;( 
         robocopy .\. "%%~dpi\." "%%~nxi" /mov /njh | find "100%"
        );= || echo; Check Your Folder\File path: "%%~dpi" "%%~nxi"
```

Comment: It can be, yes. There are dozens of combinations of folders in there leading up to 8 directories deep at the most.

Comment: so, test your new code!!!

Comment: let's delete the last comments of no use to third-party users

Comment: Sorry, I thought I unchecked the previous ones and such. Thanks for the help. I changed the answer to reflect your work and not the response I made before.

Comment: Relex, you are welcome hee.. And I thought that your little experience here would result in this action... But I took the risk by editing your answer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Duplicate error probably means that the file you tried moving already exists in the destination? Check if the file exists before moving

```
@echo off
set dir=C:\Users\user\texture\
set mask=ListedFiles.txt

cd "%dir%"
for /r %%# in (%mask%) do (
    if exist "%%~nx#" (
        echo File "%%~nx#" already exists.
    ) else (
        echo move "%%~#" "%%~nx#"
        echo mklink /h "%%~#" "%%~nx#"
    )
)
pause
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That failed to process as it doesn't know what "continue" is.
```
File "ListedFiles.txt" already exists.
'continue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have the code to list the directories and move the files to main folder. Maybe this will help? I removed the systemlink in this latest version.

```
set dir="C:\Users\user\texture"
set mask=*.bmp

cd "%dir%"
for /r %%# in (%mask%) do move "%%~#"
pause
```
If I we can reverse or undo the move I did in the above code, that would be exactly what I need.

Comment: set dir="C:\Users\user\texture"
 
set mask=*.bmp cd "%dir%" for /r %%# in (%mask%) do move "%%~#"
 
pause

Comment: Oh I am sorry, maybe I learned to much python , maybe someone more-able in batch can help, or you should try PowerShell scripts

Comment: Alright, I have edited the answer to use an `else` block

Comment: What o you mean by reverse or undo the code? I mean, do you want to remove those created symlinks?

Comment: Sorry, I misworded that there. I want to effctively "undo" the move of files back to their original directories listed in the ListedFiles.txt

Comment: If I got that right, you can just again loop the same way you did, you just have to _swap_ the parameters of `move` command

Answer (score 0):

You did not reply to my request to give an example of what would be in ListedFiles.txt so I have to guess based on what you changed since then.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to move *.bmp to a subfolder with the same name.

The code would be like this:

```
cd /d C:\Users\user\texture\

for %%f IN (*.bmp) DO move "%%f" "%%~nf\%%f"
```

An example move would do: myimg.bmp to myimg\myimg.bmp

Keep in mind that the /r is recursive mode, that would not work as it would find the same file, getting in an endless loop, pushing the file further and further down an infinite path until you exceed the maximum depth.

Also, the directory must exist too.